# Problem with reallocating array during runtime in Cpp

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to create an array data structure in C++ using classes. The idea is that the array has a predefined length to it and whenever there is need for extra space, the array gets reallocated to double it's previous length. But, there is something wrong with the code that I am unable to figure out. It displays garbage values for items that should have been allocated.

Following is the relevant code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Array
{
    private:
        int length = 8;
        int occupied_length = 0;
        int* array = new int[length];

        void reallocate_array()
        {
            array = (int*) realloc(array, length*2);
            length = length * 2;
        }
    public:
        Array()
        {
            cout << "How many elements do you want in the array: ";
            cin >> occupied_length;
            
            if (occupied_length > length) // In case array is full, it needs to be reallocated
                reallocate_array();

            for (int i = 0; i < occupied_length; i++)
                cin >> *(array + i);
            Print();
        }
        ~Array() { delete array; }
        void insert(int pos, int data)
        {
            if (pos > occupied_length) {cout << "Invalid Position!\n"; return; }

            occupied_length += 1;
            if (occupied_length >  length) { reallocate_array(); }

            if (pos == occupied_length){ *(array+occupied_length) = data; return;}
    
            for(int i = occupied_length-2; i >= pos-1; i--)
                *(array+i+1) = *(array+i);
            *(array + pos - 1) = data;
        }
        int size()
        {
            return occupied_length;
        }
        void Print()
        {
            for(int i =0; i <occupied_length; i++) { cout << *(array+i) << " "; }
            cout << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Array arr;
    arr.insert(7,45);
    arr.Print();
    arr.insert(3,35);
    arr.Print();
    arr.insert(4,86);
    arr.Print();
    cout << arr.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program is as follows:
[image]

On top of that, the program does not immediately stop execution after the last cout statement. It waits for a second or two.

Comment: Lots of issues with this code. 1) You cannot use `realloc` and `new` on the same memory 2) You double the memory each time, but you start with a length of zero, what do you think two times zero is? 3) Don't ask questions in constructors, that means you cannot create an `Array` without asking a question, instead ask the question in `main` and pass the answer to the constructor as a parameter.

Comment: 4) No copy constructor or assignment operator. Any code with copies or assigns an array will crash.

Comment: 5) Unless I'm very much mistaken `*(array+occupied_length) = data;` should be `*(array+occupied_length-1) = data;`. There's actually no need to treat insertion at the end of an array as a special case.

Comment: So, plenty to work on. The use of realloc, the resizing strategy, and the question in the constructor seem like the biggest issues to me. The constructor should just allocate at the requested size, the doubling approach should just be in the insert method, and watch out for doubling an array which has zero size.

Comment: 'waits for a second or two'. That's likely to be a crash caused by your array destructor freeing memory when the heap has been corrupted. The corruption being caused by one or more of the bugs mentioned above.

Comment: thanks @john. 1) What do you suggest I use to reallocate memory in conjunction to new operator? Or should I just use calloc? 2) About doubling an array with size 0, I set the initial length to 8. Upon creation of array object, is it set to 0?

Comment: My apologies, I misread the code, setting the length to 8 avoids the problem I was talking about

Comment: You realloc with length*2. But you don't include sizeof(int), which the new operator includes for you. It should be sizeof(int)*length*2. Yet another reason why mixing realloc and new is a bad idea (which is UB anyway). If you need realloc then use malloc and free everywhere.

Comment: You can use calloc, realloc and free. The issue with these functions in C++ is that they don't call constructors. That's not a problem with an array of `int` but it would be a problem with an array of `std::string` for example. There is no 'realloc' for memory allocated with `new`, you just have to use `new` to create a new array, copy over the data, and then `delete[]` the old array.

Comment: Required reading: [Rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Answer (score 1):

To sum up what comments are saying:

- Don't mix malloc/calloc/realloc and new/delete. Undefined behavior awaits.
- When using `realloc` the second argument is the number of *bytes*, so you would need to multiply by `sizeof(int)`. But again, *don't use `realloc`*.
- You will need to follow the [rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) when implementing a class which manages its own memory, or double frees and other hijinks will ensue.

You might as well make this a templated class to avoid repeating yourself.

```cpp
template <
    typename T,
    std::size_t INIT_SZ=8,
    typename GROW_BY=std::size_t,
    GROW_BY GROWTH_FACTOR=2
>
class Array {
    using self_type = Array<T, INIT_SZ, GROW_BY, GROWTH_FACTOR>;

    std::size_t allocated_size;
    std::size_t occupied_size;
    T *array;

    void grow() {
        std::size_t new_size = static_cast<std::size_t>(allocated_size * GROWTH_FACTOR);
        if (new_size == 0) new_size = INIT_SZ;

        T *new_array = new T[new_size];

        std::copy(array, array+occupied_size, new_array);

        delete[] array;

        array = new_array;
        allocated_size = new_size;
    }

public:
    // Constructor
    Array()
    : allocated_size(INIT_SZ),
      occupied_size(0),
      array(new T[INIT_SZ])
    { }

    // Destructor
    ~Array() { delete[] array; }

    // Copy constructor
    Array(const self_type& other)
    : allocated_size(other.allocated_size),
      occupied_size(other.occupied_size),
      array(new T[allocated_size])
    {
        std::copy(other.array, other.array + occupied_size, array);
    }

    // Copy assignment
    self_type& operator=(const self_type& other) {
        if (this == &other) return *this;

        delete[] array;

        allocated_size = other.allocated_size;
        occupied_size = other.occupied_size;

        std::copy(other.array, other.array + other.occupied_size, array);

        return *this;
    }

    // Move constructor
    Array(self_type&& other)
    : allocated_size(other.allocated_size),
      occupied_size(other.occupied_size),
      array(other.array)
    {
        other.occupied_size = 0;
        other.allocated_size = INIT_SZ;
        other.array = nullptr;
    }

    // Move assignment
    self_type& operator=(self_type&& other) {
        allocated_size = other.allocated_size;
        occupied_size = other.allocated_size;
        array = nullptr;

        std::swap(array, other.array);

        return *this;
    }

    void push_back(T val) {
        if (occupied_size == allocated_size) grow();

        array[occupied_size++] = val;
    }
};
```

Of course, with the contents private you'll need to implement public member functions to gain access to the data and size. You'll also want to implement [iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator).

Comment: Got it. There's a lot I need to understand. Thanks for your input